# Installing PCL after Hydro

Tags: pcl, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I have some issues installing PCL with Hydro. As I understand it PCL is not included in ros-hydro-desktop-full anymore so after I installed ROS I tried to install PCL with

```
sudo apt-get install libpcl-all.
```

However this only installs ~1.5KB of files which is obviously not normal. The pcl header files are nowhere to be found (/usr/local/include is empty). This is a problem since the pcl_ros header files include the pcl header files which means that I cannot compile anything.

What am I missing here?

Thanks a lot for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188792/installing-pcl-after-hydro/) by [NKor](https://answers.ros.org/users/19925/nkor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`libpcl-all` doesn't appear to be a valid Ubuntu package.

Ubuntu packages are usually split into runtime packages which contain the shared libraries, and development packages, which contain the headers and build files, and have a `-dev` suffix.

I suspect you need to install the `libpcl-1.7-all-dev` package.

Note also that locally installed headers get installed into /usr/local/include, such as when building from source, but headers for system packages, installed through the package manager, are usually installed directly into /usr/include. (This helps make sure that the user doesn't mess with the package manager, and the package manager doesn't overwrite the user's files).

On my system, with libpcl-1.7-all-dev installed, the PCL headers are in `/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0